# Exception: Данные, введенные в ячейку , не соответствуют правилам проверки

Tags: google-apps-script, таблицы

Есть лист, в первом столбце стоит проверка данных. Т.к. данные не выбирают,а копируют из другой табл, то не смотря на то,что значение не соответствует, оно все-равно вставляется в ячейку. Когда начинает работать скрипт, он берет весь лист и вываливается с ошибкой "Exception: Данные, введенные в ячейку A56, не соответствуют правилам проверки.". Как решить такую проблему, руками постоянно править эти ячейки не очень то удобно.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: К сожалению, это вопрос с просьбой об отладке. Так это не работает. Пришлите пример в виде Таблице, укажите, какие параметры и код вы уже использовали.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Вопрос закрыт. Удалить правила проверки. Корректность данных в ячейке проверять в коде.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Замените в настройках **Проверки данных** галку **Запрещать ввод данных** > **Показывать предупреждения**